# AdonisJS 5, dynamically connect database

Tags: node.js, typescript, backend, adonis.js, lucid

Hi used Adonis Js 5 with the new version. I have multiple database clients with the same database structure, can I create a new database connection without declaring the config at config/database.ts? it means I can create a connection on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes finally I can make it, with this:

```
Database.manager.patch(this.database.name, {
  client: 'mysql',
  connection: {
    host: Env.get('DB_HOST'),
    port: Env.get('DB_PORT'),
    user: this.database.username,
    password: this.database.password,
    database: this.database.name,
  },
  debug: Env.get('DB_DEBUG', false),
})
Database.manager.connect(this.database.name)
```